# Tag menu in main screen

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, tag-watching

On the home page, there is no tag-submenu (add to interesting/add to ignore) - it is only visible on **tag** view.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is still experimental.